# Crazy bushy Muscadine/Scuppernong vines -- what did I do wrong

Tags: grape-vine

So, I pruned my grapes per instructions (both of the guy I bought them from and after watching many internet videos).  I mean I trimmed them way back.  However, see pics below for how they grew this summer.

I had it pruned back to just spurs on the main vines, and thought I'd trimmed the trunks sufficiently.  However, see this year's vines:

[image: side]

[image: front]

Any suggestions about what I did wrong?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Grapes grow a lot of vines in one season , then you cut off a lot for the next growing season.